# Deserialize Json with array

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I need to deserialize a json like this:

```
[[[[{"string1":"AB","date1":"01/01/1900 8:59:00","date2":"01/01/1900 9:28:00","col":["VO","SC","VD","LF","SR","TT","BN","MM","HH","HH","YY","ZZ"]}],[{"string1":"AB","date1":"01/01/1900 9:02:00","date2":"01/01/1900 9:30:00","col":["VO","SC","VD","LF","LP","VV","FF","MM","HH","HH","YY","ZZ"]}]]]]
```

I've tried with the following code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var d = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

But I'm missing something and I can't get the information correctly.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: You don't showed how you try to access data

Comment: `[[[[{` means a lot of arrays... are you sure you're calling the correct amount of arrays? such as `d[0][0][0].string1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array of arrays of arrays of arrays of arrays. A pure engineering genius must have designed this data structure.

Anyway, here's how to deserialize and access its properties:

```
string json = "[[[[{\"string1\":\"AB\",\"date1\":\"01/01/1900 8:59:00\",\"date2\":\"01/01/1900 9:28:00\",\"col\":[\"VO\",\"SC\",\"VD\",\"LF\",\"SR\",\"TT\",\"BN\",\"MM\",\"HH\",\"HH\",\"YY\",\"ZZ\"]}],[{\"string1\":\"AB\",\"date1\":\"01/01/1900 9:02:00\",\"date2\":\"01/01/1900 9:30:00\",\"col\":[\"VO\",\"SC\",\"VD\",\"LF\",\"LP\",\"VV\",\"FF\",\"MM\",\"HH\",\"HH\",\"YY\",\"ZZ\"]}]]]]";
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var d = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

foreach (dynamic item in d[0][0][0])
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["string1"]);
    Console.WriteLine(item["date1"]);
    Console.WriteLine(item["date2"]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine but the problem is that with this code I only get the first element. How can I get a list or something?

Comment: `d[0][0][0]` is the list. You can loop through it. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: I can solve with this:
`for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
 foreach (dynamic item in d[0][0][i])
 {
  Console.WriteLine(item["string1"]);
  Console.WriteLine(item["date1"]);
  Console.WriteLine(item["date2"]);
  ...
 }
}`

But I don't like because I don't know the lenght of the json... 
Any Idea?

Comment: Solved:

`foreach (dynamic item in d[0][0])
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[0]["string1"]);
    Console.WriteLine(item[0]["date1"]);
    Console.WriteLine(item[0]["date2"]);
    ...
}` Thanks a lot for all!

Answer (score 0):

Your json is valild

```
[
    [
        [
            [
                {
                    "string1": "AB",
                    "date1": "01/01/1900 8:59:00",
                    "date2": "01/01/1900 9:28:00",
                    "col": [
                        "VO",
                        "SC",
                        "VD",
                        "LF",
                        "SR",
                        "TT",
                        "BN",
                        "MM",
                        "HH",
                        "HH",
                        "YY",
                        "ZZ"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "string1": "AB",
                    "date1": "01/01/1900 9:02:00",
                    "date2": "01/01/1900 9:30:00",
                    "col": [
                        "VO",
                        "SC",
                        "VD",
                        "LF",
                        "LP",
                        "VV",
                        "FF",
                        "MM",
                        "HH",
                        "HH",
                        "YY",
                        "ZZ"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I check it with jsonlint.com

I think your problem because you have nested array.